# sharepoint search server not installed on wss 3.0 box how do i add it?

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I have wss 3.0 set up and in use, but the search is not working.  most of the  troubleshooting starts with "open central administration, click Operations then Services On Server, then start and stop WSS Search Server".. but there is no search server listed.. only services are central admin, help search, incoming email, and web app.

any ideas?

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although i voted to move to serverfault, here's my 2 cents:

use the following command in a command window (of course in the C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\BIN folder):

first, trigger a (re)install of the services using:

```
psconfig -cmd services -install
```

Now start the wss search service using:

```
stsadm -o spsearch -action start -farmperformancelevel "PartlyReduced" -farmserviceaccount "WSSSEARCH_ACCOUNT" -farmservicepassword "WSSSEARCH_ACCOUNT_PW" -farmcontentaccessaccount "WSSCONTENT_ACCOUNT" -farmcontentaccesspassword "WSSCONTENT_ACCOUNT_PW" -indexlocation "DIRECTORYPATH_TO_INDEX" -databaseserver "DB_SERVER_NAME" -databasename "DB_NAME"
```

where you replace all the stuff i capitalized here with your own information.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to download and install the search server. you can get it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/en/us/search-server-express.aspx).

Comment: AFAIK WSS search is separate from MSSx, although you can install MSSx on top of WSS, WSS by itself should still have the ability to index its own content.

Answer (score 0):

1) You may need to start the service on a different server.  At the top of the services on server page, there is a dropdown to change the currently selected server.  If a server is installed as WFE only it can't host wss search.  Try looking at another server

2) Do view:all and see what shows up.

Caveat: I mainly work with moss, haven't worked with wss in a while.